# Solving $x^2 + x + 1 > 0$

Tags: inequality

I'm having a lot of trouble solving the above inequality in the "standard" way. I know by the plot that $x$ can be any value, but I can't seem to get to that answer.

Here are my steps:

$$x^2 + x + 1 > 0$$

$$x^2 + x > -1 $$

$$x (x + 1) > -1 $$

So now i check when both $x$ and $x+1$ are bigger than $-1$ and when both $x$ and $x+1$ are smaller than $-1$

First system of equations:

$$ x > -1$$

$$ x + 1 > -1 $$ turns into: $$ x > -2 $$

So the answer to the first set of equations is : $ x > -1 $

Second system of equations:

$$ x < -1$$

$$ x + 1 < -1 $$ turns into: $$ x < -2 $$

So the answer to the second set of equations is : $ x < -2 $

Which would give us a final answer of 
$$x < -2, x > 1$$, which I know is wrong.

My question is: where is my mistake in all this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: first step is to find the routs of the left side of your initial inequality.
because there are no routs for that and your function is continues you have that either it is always $\gt0$ or always $\lt0 $ , to conclude which one you can simply try any $x \in R$  and see what is its sign.

Comment: Can also complete the square: $x^2+x+1=(x+1/2)^2+3/4>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The "standard way" to solve $ax^2+bx+c>0$ covers all cases, as far as I remember it.

Comment: Guys I'm just confused where in my logic I was wrong, I know what the answer is but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: "where is my mistake in all this?" Let us reconsider the step: "So now i check when both x and x+1 are bigger than -1 and when both x and x+1 are smaller than -1" This is wrong, since these two cases (the case $x>-1$ and $x+1>-1$ and the case $x<-1$ and $x+1<-1$) do not exhaust, and in fact are not even related to, the inequality $x(x+1)>-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic falters at the step $x(x+1)>-1 \Rightarrow x>-1 \wedge x+1>-1$  and the corresponding assuming $x<-1$ and $x+1<-1$. That $x(x+1)>-1$ has two possibilities, \begin{align} -1<&x(x+1)\leq0 \\ 0<&x(x+1)\end{align}In the first case is only true if $x\leq0$ and $x+1\geq0$, so $-1\leq x\leq0$. The second case is possible if $x<0$ and $x+1<0$ or $x>0$ and $x+1>0$. The first case occurs precisely when $x<-1$, the second for $x>0$. From these, we conclude it holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Your logic says $xy>z$ implies $x>z \wedge y>z$ or $xy>z$ implies $x<z\wedge y<z$. This is not true! If $x=z=-1, y=0$, then $$0=(-1)0>-1\not\Rightarrow -1>-1 \wedge 0>-1$$ and the same for the other case, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing $ab > -1$ doesn't let you split into the cases you give. For instance, $a=-1/3$, $b=-3$.  I can't tell for sure, but you seem to be committing the error of lots of beginning algebra students:  They forget that $0$ is special.  If $ab=0$ then one of $a$ or $b$ is zero.  What works for $0$ doesn't work for other numbers, but they'll get excited and write "$x(x-1)=-1$ so either $x=-1$ or $x-1=-1$."  It seems like your error is similar, but with inequalities.

Comment: Thank you, that was the mistake I was committing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Your function has no zeros (try p-q-formula). So its a parabola, that doesn't cross the x-axis. So the leading factor $\textbf{1}x^2 + x + 1$ tells you that the function is positive on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hi Yaddle, yes, I know that the inequality is true for all values of x, I'm just confused about why I couldn't reach that answer the "usual" way

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong when you say:

> now i check when both $x$ and $x+1$ are bigger than $-1$ and when both $x$ and $x+1$ are smaller than $-1$

supposing that this gives the solution of $x(x+1)>-1$.

This is false. You can test, as an example: $x=-\frac{3}{2}<-1$ and $x+1=-\frac{1}{2} >-1$ that gives:
$x(x+1)=3/4>-1$

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see how your method could have worked, since you don’t seem to have multiplied $x$ and $x+1$ anywhere. Following your lead, though, I would split the situation into three exhaustive and mutually exclusive cases: (1) $x\le-1$; (2) $x\ge0$; and (3) $-1<x<0$. My task is to show that in each of these three cases, $x(x+1)>-1$.
\begin{align}
x\le-1&\Longrightarrow x+1\le0\Longrightarrow x(x+1)\ge0>-1\quad\text{(good)}\\
x\ge0&\Longrightarrow x+1>0\Longrightarrow x(x+1)\ge0>-1\quad\text{(good)}\\
-1<x<0&\Longrightarrow0<x+1<1\text{ and }0<-x<1\Longrightarrow-x(x+1)<1
\Longrightarrow x(x+1)>-1\quad\text{(good)}\,,
\end{align}
which does it.

(**But** I think the right way to do it without Calculus would be to complete the square: $x^2+x+1=\bigl(x+\frac12\bigr)^2+\frac34$, clearly always positive.)